# Outlook 2007: disabling the prompt to enable instant search

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

There is a permanent yellow bar under the toolbar in Outlook 2007 saying "Click here to enable instant search".

[image]

When I click on it, the following message appears:

[image]

I click No, but the annoying yellow bar is still there. How can I get rid of it? I don't want to install the Instant Search feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools > Options > Other > Advanced Options > Uncheck "Show prompts to enable Instant Search"